# Run Chartjs Dart example

Tags: dart, chart.js, dart-editor

I'm trying to run the chartjs example of the dart port but It seems not to work.
See screenshot with error message.

Any Idea where is the problem? Thanks

the source code for the example can be downloaded [Chartjs Dart port Example](https://bitbucket.org/ips/chart.dart)

lib/chart.dart source:

```dart
library chart;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

part 'src/base.dart';
part 'src/line.dart';
part 'src/bar.dart';
part 'src/bool.dart';
part 'src/animation.dart';
```

example/web/chart.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chart.css">
    <script type="application/dart" src="chart.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

example/web/chart.dart

```dart
library chart;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:chart/chart.dart';


void main() {


  Line chart = new Line({
    'labels' : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"],
    'datasets' : [
                {
                  'fillColor' : "rgba(220,20,20,0.5)",
                  'strokeColor' : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                  'pointColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  'pointStrokeColor' : "#f00",
                  'data' : [1,4,5,2,5,6,3,7]
                },
                {
                  'fillColor' : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                  'strokeColor' : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  'pointColor' : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  'pointStrokeColor' : "#fff",
                  'data' : [3,-1,0,4,4,-2,4,1]
                },
                {
                  'fillColor' : "clear",
                  'strokeColor' : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  'pointColor' : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  'pointStrokeColor' : "#fff",
                  'data' : [-3,-3,-1,-4,-4,-3,-4,-1]
                }
    ]
  }, {
    'scaleOverride' : true, 
    'scaleMinValue' : 0.0, 
    'scaleMaxValue' : 35.0, 
    'scaleStepValue' : null, 
    'bezierCurve' : true, 
    'animation' : false,
    'titleText' : 'testest'     
    });


  Line chart2 = new Line({
      'labels' : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
      'datasets' : [
                  {
                    'fillColor' : "rgba(123,244,220,0.5)",
                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointStrokeColor' : "#fff",
                    'data' : [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
                  }
      ]

    }, {
      'animationEasing': 'easeOutElastic',
      'animation' : true,
      'bezierCurve' : true, 
      }
    );

  Bool chartBool = new Bool({
      'labels' : ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag"],
      'datasets' : [
                  {
                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(255,10,10,1)",
                    'data' : [{'x':0, 'y':0},{'x':2, 'y':0},{'x':3, 'y':1},{'x':20, 'y':0},{'x':30, 'y':0},{'x':40, 'y':0},{'x':45, 'y':0},{'x':63, 'y':0},{'x':100, 'y':0},{'x':123, 'y':1},{'x':128, 'y':0},{'x':130, 'y':0}]
                  }
                  ]

    }, {
      'animationEasing': 'easeOutElastic',
      'animation' : true
      }
    );

  Bar bar = new Bar({
                      'labels' : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
                      'datasets' : [
                                  {
                                    'fillColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    'data' : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'fillColor' : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)",
                                    'data' : [28,48,40,19,null,27,100]
                                  }
                                  ]

  }, null);

  Bar bar2 = new Bar({
                      'labels' : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
                      'datasets' : [
                                  {
                                    'fillColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    'data' : [55,59,90,59,56,55,60]
                                  }]

  }, 
  {
    'titleText' : 'testest'     
  });

  DivElement containerBool = new DivElement();
  containerBool.style.height ='400px';
  containerBool.style.width =  '100%';
  document.body.children.add(containerBool);
  chartBool.show(containerBool);

  DivElement container = new DivElement();
  container.style.height ='400px';
  container.style.width =  '100%';
  document.body.children.add(container);
  chart.show(container);

  DivElement container2 = new DivElement();
  container2.style.height ='400px';
  container2.style.width =  '100%';
  document.body.children.add(container2);
  chart2.show(container2);

  DivElement container3 = new DivElement();
  container3.style.height ='400px';
  container3.style.width =  '100%';
  document.body.children.add(container3);
  bar.show(container3);

  DivElement container4 = new DivElement();
  container4.style.height ='400px';
  container4.style.width =  '100%';
  document.body.children.add(container4);
  bar2.show(container4);


}
```

[image: Chartjs Dart error]

Comment: Can you please post the code of a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem. The error message is so generic that it doesn't allow any conlusions.

Comment: Link to download source code added, the source is also added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a bug in the example. Maybe the library was changed and the example not yet tested with the new version.

If you add two values to the map it works though

```dart
 Bool chartBool = new Bool({
      'labels' : ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag"],
      'datasets' : [
                  {
                    'name': 'bla',
                    'date': 'somedate',
                    'strokeColor' : "rgba(255,10,10,1)",
```

I just added the two lines `name': 'bla'`,`'date': 'somedate'`. It looks these values are just used as tooltip and the content doesn't really matter to overcome the exception.